# Is the sentence structure “As A did something, B was doing something” correct?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

For example,

> As Jerry and Ming argued about the many possible tile colors for the floor of the new ice-cream parlor, Maria was thinking about whether to paint the walls or wallpaper them.

Is the structure of this sentence correct?

Comment: Perfectly normal structure.

Comment: @ WS2: How about this one "As A was doing sth, B did sth." Any difference between the two structures?

Comment: Like *As I was working hard the rest of them sat with their feet up*? Fine.

Comment: @ WS2: Exactly. Are these two structures the same or they might have semantic nuances?

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely correct: substitute 'while' for 'as', and the meaning becomes clearer.